# How do I burn tokens with this code?

Tags: go-ethereum

Someone help me with how I can burn tokens with this code or send out remaining tokens out to admin wallet. Thanks!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a / b;
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract ForeignToken {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool);
}

contract ERC20Basic {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

interface Token { 
    function distr(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool);
    function totalSupply() constant public returns (uint256 supply);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256 balance);
}

contract PUMPHODL is ERC20 {

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address owner = msg.sender;

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    mapping (address => bool) public blacklist;

    string public constant name = "PUMPHODL";
    string public constant symbol = "PHOD";
    uint public constant decimals = 8;

    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000e8;
    uint256 public totalDistributed = 300000000e8;
    uint256 public totalRemaining = totalSupply.sub(totalDistributed);
    uint256 public value;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    event Distr(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
    event DistrFinished();

    event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 value);

    bool public distributionFinished = false;

    modifier canDistr() {
        require(!distributionFinished);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyWhitelist() {
        require(blacklist[msg.sender] == false);
        _;
    }

    function PUMPHODL () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        value = 10000e8;
        distr(owner, totalDistributed);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        if (newOwner != address(0)) {
            owner = newOwner;
        }
    }

    function enableWhitelist(address[] addresses) onlyOwner public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            blacklist[addresses[i]] = false;
        }
    }

    function disableWhitelist(address[] addresses) onlyOwner public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            blacklist[addresses[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function finishDistribution() onlyOwner canDistr public returns (bool) {
        distributionFinished = true;
        DistrFinished();
        return true;
    }

    function distr(address _to, uint256 _amount) canDistr private returns (bool) {
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.add(_amount);
        totalRemaining = totalRemaining.sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        Distr(_to, _amount);
        Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);
        return true;

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }
    }

    function airdrop(address[] addresses) onlyOwner canDistr public {

        require(addresses.length <= 255);
        require(value <= totalRemaining);

        for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            require(value <= totalRemaining);
            distr(addresses[i], value);
        }

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }
    }

    function distribution(address[] addresses, uint256 amount) onlyOwner canDistr public {

        require(addresses.length <= 255);
        require(amount <= totalRemaining);

        for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            require(amount <= totalRemaining);
            distr(addresses[i], amount);
        }

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }
    }

    function distributeAmounts(address[] addresses, uint256[] amounts) onlyOwner canDistr public {

        require(addresses.length <= 255);
        require(addresses.length == amounts.length);

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            require(amounts[i] <= totalRemaining);
            distr(addresses[i], amounts[i]);

            if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
                distributionFinished = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function () external payable {
            getTokens();
     }

    function getTokens() payable canDistr onlyWhitelist public {

        if (value > totalRemaining) {
            value = totalRemaining;
        }

        require(value <= totalRemaining);

        address investor = msg.sender;
        uint256 toGive = value;

        distr(investor, toGive);

        if (toGive > 0) {
            blacklist[investor] = true;
        }

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }

        value = value.div(100000).mul(99999);
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    // mitigates the ERC20 short address attack
    modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint size) {
        assert(msg.data.length >= size + 4);
        _;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) public returns (bool success) {

        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_amount <= balances[msg.sender]);

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32) public returns (bool success) {

        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_amount <= balances[_from]);
        require(_amount <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_amount);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 spend/approval race condition
        if (_value != 0 && allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0) { return false; }
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant public returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function getTokenBalance(address tokenAddress, address who) constant public returns (uint){
        ForeignToken t = ForeignToken(tokenAddress);
        uint bal = t.balanceOf(who);
        return bal;
    }

    function withdraw() onlyOwner public {
        uint256 etherBalance = this.balance;
        owner.transfer(etherBalance);
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public {
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
        // no need to require value <= totalSupply, since that would imply the
        // sender's balance is greater than the totalSupply, which *should* be an assertion failure

        address burner = msg.sender;
        balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.sub(_value);
        Burn(burner, _value);
    }

    function withdrawForeignTokens(address _tokenContract) onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
        ForeignToken token = ForeignToken(_tokenContract);
        uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        return token.transfer(owner, amount);
    }
}
```

(from: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7444e28d8d8db540054271b1e9a9c2573aaf01b7#code)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to burn tokens then you need to be the "owner" of the contract, which means you have the private keys for "0x7be0b5fc0890659bf4debab8837d0822ae1e41cd"

```
function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public {
```

There is a "nice" method in the code however,

```
function withdraw() onlyOwner public {
    uint256 etherBalance = this.balance;
    owner.transfer(etherBalance);
}
```

that will effectively transfer all the eth in that contract to the owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public {
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    // no need to require value <= totalSupply, since that would imply the
    // sender's balance is greater than the totalSupply, which *should* be an assertion failure

    address burner = msg.sender;
    balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
    totalDistributed = totalDistributed.sub(_value);
    Burn(burner, _value);
}
```

call this function from owner account and give number of token you want to burn but keep in mind burn token amount is less than owner account balance with this method totalSupply decreased in other method totalSupply remain same

Comment: if i should burn tokens, does it mean that the amount i wanna burn that is in the owner address will be removed?

Comment: in common term burn means remove from token supply and also owner account if you transfer it to contract address whats the meaning of write burn function it could easily doable with transfer method